# MongoDB: How to find specific value in nested array, if found then show only that array not all?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to **find** id "D0182" in **client_id array** if found then only it will show the client_id document, but it is showing me the whole document.

Here is my query -

`db.getCollection('news').find({"newsSources.client_id":"343a","date": "2021-01-22"},  {"_id":0,"newsSources.title" :1, "newsSources.client_id":1})`

Comment: Can you post the document as a code snippet instead of image!

Comment: And Id know that the `client_id` is inside the `newsSources`. Do you need to filter only the object inside the array or you need to get all documents which has the `client_id` in your collection?

Comment: as you can see in the image above client_id: ["W0086"] is also displayed, I am trying  to show only that [client_id] array which has the value ["D0182"] , if not then it should hide not displayed

Comment: @varman I am using MongoDB shell only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation to filter out objects from array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newsSources": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$newsSources",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "D0108",
              "$$this.clientId"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZPSAnyQgeBs)**